# powershell is missing the terminator error?

Tags: powershell, cmd, char, windows-server-2008-r2, win32-process

I try to run this command from cmd :

```
powershell -command "& {&'get-wmiobject Win32_Product | Format-Table Name, LocalPackage}"
```

... it's work on windows 7 but on my windows server 2008 R2 x64-bitIi got this error :

```psh
 The string starting:
At line:1 char:5
+ & {& <<<< 'get-wmiobject Win32_Product | Format-Table Name, LocalPackage}
is missing the terminator: '.
At line:1 char:68
+ & {&'get-wmiobject Win32_Product | Format-Table Name, LocalPackage} <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (get-wmiobject W..., LocalPackage}:
   String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

How can I solve this error? I need it to run from cmd !!

Comment: You do appear to be missing a terminating single quote character per the error. Put one after localpackage

Comment: powershell -command "& {&'get-wmiobject Win32_Product | Format-Table Name, LocalPackage'}" ?? not working

Comment: Not working as in throwing the same error? What's the error after adding the missing '?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both variants work here:

```
powershell -command "get-wmiobject Win32_Product | Format-Table Name, LocalPackage"
powershell -command "&{get-wmiobject Win32_Product | Format-Table Name, LocalPackage}"
```

Comment: they did not work i got the same error for both :: At line:1 char:16
+ &{get-wmiobject <<<<  Win32_Product | Format-Table Name, LocalPackage}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMExcept 
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands 
   .GetWmiObjectCommand

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the powershell version then.

Comment: how to know that ??

Comment: Just a guess as it works here with win10pro and actual PS Version?

Comment: it's working on windows 7 and 10 but windows server 2008 R2 x64-bit it's not work from cmd windows directly .. if i opened powershell and then execute get-wmiobject Win32_Product | Format-Table Name, LocalPackage it's working .... but i dont need if from powershell i need it from cmd